# Mutual ssl authentication in simple ECHO client/server [Python / sockets / ssl modules], ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, pyopenssl

I would like to have a mutual authentication in my echo client/server program. I'm using `python 2.7.12 and the`ssl` module on

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I've generated client's and server's certificates and keys using the `openssl` commands:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out client.pem -keyout client.key
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out server.pem -keyout server.key
```

I want the client to authenticate the server, and I want the server to authenticate the client. However, the code below shows some errors, at server's side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssl_server.py", line 18, in <module>
    secure_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True, certfile="server.pem", keyfile="server.key")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 933, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 601, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 830, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

At client' side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssl_client.py", line 18, in <module>
    secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST, server_side=False, certfile="client.pem", keyfile="client.key")
TypeError: wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'certfile'
```

Server's code:

```
#!/bin/usr/env python
import socket
import ssl
import pprint

#server
if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 1234

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    client, fromaddr = server_socket.accept()
    secure_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True, certfile="server.pem", keyfile="server.key")

    print repr(secure_sock.getpeername())
    print secure_sock.cipher()
    print pprint.pformat(secure_sock.getpeercert())
    cert = secure_sock.getpeercert()
    print cert

    # verify client
    if not cert or ('commonName', 'test') not in cert['subject'][4]: raise Exception("ERROR")

    try:
        data = secure_sock.read(1024)
        secure_sock.write(data)
    finally:
        secure_sock.close()
        server_socket.close()
```

Client's code:

```
import socket
import ssl

# client
if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 1234

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.load_verify_locations('server.pem')

    if ssl.HAS_SNI:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST, server_side=False, certfile="client.pem", keyfile="client.key")
    else:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=False, certfile="client.pem", keyfile="client.key")

    cert = secure_sock.getpeercert()
    print cert

    # verify server
    if not cert or ('commonName', 'test') not in cert['subject'][4]: raise Exception("ERROR")

    secure_sock.write('hello')
    secure_sock.read(1024)

    secure_sock.close()
    sock.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: `ssl.wrap_socket()` has `certfile` parameter. `SSLContext.wrap_socket()` does not. You're confusing the two classes.

Comment: @pbuck: I can't find the difference between them. Could you plase explain it a bit? Which of them should I use and why? Are they capable of doing the same things?

Comment: my point was just a simple bug / typo on the client side which was throwing the exception. Looks like you've got a much more thorough answer from @ilario-pierbattista below!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically the server need to share with the client his certificate and vice versa (look the `ca_certs` parameter). The main problem with your code is that the handshake were never executed. Also, the `Common Name` string position depends on how many field did specified in the certificate. I had been lazy, so my `subject` has only 4 fiels, and `Common Name` is the last of them.

Now it works (feel free to ask for further details).

#### Server

```
#!/bin/usr/env python
import socket
import ssl
import pprint

#server
if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 1234

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    client, fromaddr = server_socket.accept()
    secure_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True, ca_certs = "client.pem", certfile="server.pem", keyfile="server.key", cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                           ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

    print repr(secure_sock.getpeername())
    print secure_sock.cipher()
    print pprint.pformat(secure_sock.getpeercert())
    cert = secure_sock.getpeercert()
    print cert

    # verify client
    if not cert or ('commonName', 'test') not in cert['subject'][3]: raise Exception("ERROR")

    try:
        data = secure_sock.read(1024)
        secure_sock.write(data)
    finally:
        secure_sock.close()
        server_socket.close()
```

#### Client

```
import socket
import ssl

# client
if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 1234

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setblocking(1);
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.load_verify_locations('server.pem')
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile="client.pem", keyfile="client.key")

    if ssl.HAS_SNI:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=False, server_hostname=HOST)
    else:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=False)

    cert = secure_sock.getpeercert()
    print cert

    # verify server
    if not cert or ('commonName', 'test') not in cert['subject'][3]: raise Exception("ERROR")

    secure_sock.write('hello')
    print secure_sock.read(1024)

    secure_sock.close()
    sock.close()
```

Take a look:

[image: Proof]

Ps: I made the client print the server response.

#### Response to comments

> On client's side you never used the context variable I've created. Does it mean it's unnecessary here?

Documentation says:

> For more sophisticated applications, the `ssl.SSLContext` class helps manage settings and certificates, which can then be inherited by SSL sockets created through the `SSLContext.wrap_socket()` method.

I've updated the code to show you the differences: the server uses `ssl.wrap_socket()`, the client `ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket()`.

> Second, what's the point in checking if ssl.HAS_SNI when the socket creation looks the same in if and else? With your approach I cant use server_hostname=HOST in socket wrapping method.

You are right, in the updated code I used `server_hostname=HOST`.

> Another thing: you're using ca_certs instead of using load_verify_locations in context I created. Why? Are those 2 methods identical?

My fault, I was using `ca_cert` as parameter of `ssl.wrap_socket()`, so I didn't used the `context` at all. Now I use it.

> And another thing: do you really need to call `secure_sock.do_handshake()` by yourself?

Nope, I forgot to remove it :)

The output is exactly the same.

Comment: Fineeee, but ... On client's side you never used the `context` variable I've created. Does it mean it's unnecessary here? Second, what's the point in checking if `ssl.HAS_SNI` when the socket creation looks the same in `if` and `else`? With your approach I cant use `server_hostname=HOST` in socket wrapping method. Another thing: you're using `ca_certs` instead of using `load_verify_locations` in context I created. Why? Are those 2 methods identical? Please don't get me wrong, I asked about those things because I do not understand them.

Comment: And another thing: do you really need to call `secure_sock.do_handshake()` by yourself?

Comment: Thank you for your questions, I've update my answer. I hope that it's clear

Comment: Thank YOU! :) I need some time to rethink all this.

Comment: If you're coming here from Google, you may have to include `context.load_default_certs()` after setting the verify mode.

Answer (score 4):

ilario-pierbattista Answer but in python 3:

- Check print function
- Check secure_sock.write(b'hello') in bytes
- Check function argument (config)

```py
def start_client_side(config):
    HOST = config['host']
    PORT = config['port']
    pemServer = config['serverpem']
    keyClient = config['clientkey']
    pemClient = config['clientpem']

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setblocking(1);
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.load_verify_locations(pemServer)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile=pemClient, keyfile=keyClient)

    if ssl.HAS_SNI:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=False, server_hostname=HOST)
    else:
        secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=False)

    cert = secure_sock.getpeercert()
    print(pprint.pformat(cert))

    # verify server
    if not cert or ('commonName', 'server.utester.local') not in itertools.chain(*cert['subject']): raise Exception("ERROR")

    secure_sock.write(b'hello')
    print(secure_sock.read(1024))

    secure_sock.close()
    sock.close()
```

```py
def start_server_side(config):
    HOST = config['host']
    PORT = config['port']
    pemServer = config['serverpem']
    keyServer = config['serverkey']
    pemClient = config['clientpem']

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    client, fromaddr = server_socket.accept()
    secure_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True, ca_certs=pemClient, certfile=pemServer,
                                  keyfile=keyServer, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                                  ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

    print(repr(secure_sock.getpeername()))
    print(secure_sock.cipher())
    cert = secure_sock.getpeercert()
    print(pprint.pformat(cert))

    # verify client
    if not cert or ('commonName', 'client.utester.local') not in itertools.chain(*cert['subject']): raise Exception("ERROR")

    try:
        data = secure_sock.read(1024)
        secure_sock.write(data)
    finally:
        secure_sock.close()
        server_socket.close()
```